# How can I plot x axis values from a .csv file?

Tags: r

I have date1 column which contains a date row. This row contains date in format dd/mm/yyyy

To plot the date values directly I'm using :

```
axis(1, at=1:5, lab=c("01/01/2013" , "01/02/2013" , "01/03/2013" , 
, "01/04/2013" , , "01/05/2013"))
```

To read the values from a .csv file I require something like ? :
axis(1, at=1:5, lab=c(date1$date))
I think I need to remove the 'at' parameter as the number of dates is dynamic.

Here is the entire code :

```
g_range <- range(0, date1$links)
plot(date1$links, type="o", col="blue", ylim=g_range, 
   axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
axis(1, at=1:5, lab=c("01/01/2013" , "01/02/2013" , "01/03/2013" , 
, "01/04/2013" , , "01/05/2013"))
box()
title(main="Additions", col.main="red", font.main=4)
axis(2, las=1, at=50*0:g_range[2])
```

This is the format of the file that is being read :

```
value , links 
18/03/2013,100 
19/03/2013,200 
20/03/2013,300 
21/03/2013,400 
22/03/2013,500
```

I'm currently reading the links column, but want to update the code to also read the date instead as now the date values are being set within the r code itself. By dynamic I mean the .csv file can contain a variable list of date & links values, so in above example there are 5 value/links pairs but there could be 6 or 7 or 8 etc...

Comment: Why not to use the default  axes?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what do you want to do , wince you don't give a reproducible example, and it is not clear what is dynamic. I think , You can use the function `axis.Date()` take an object containing dates and produce an axis with appropriate labels.

here an example:

[image]

I create some dummy plot...

```
random.dates <- seq(as.Date("01/01/2013",format='%d/%m/%Y'),
                    as.Date("01/05/2013",format='%d/%m/%Y'),length.out=50)
plot(random.dates, 1:50, xaxt="n",main='pretty axes dates',type='o')
```

Then I coerce your  vector of string to a a vector of dates

```
at =as.Date(c("01/01/2013" , "01/02/2013" , "01/03/2013"  , 
              "01/04/2013" ,  "01/05/2013"),format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Note in the call of `axis.Date` the argument format is not the same that the one used to coerce string to dates...

```
axis.Date(1,at=at,format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

**EDIT***

Ho to read a csv file:

```
dat <- read.table(text='value , links 
18/03/2013,100 
19/03/2013,200 
20/03/2013,300 
21/03/2013,400 
22/03/2013,500',header=TRUE,sep=',')


dat$value <- as.Date(dat$value,format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: I've updated the question in an attempt to be more clear. I'm currently reading the links column, but want to update the code to also read the date instead as now the date values are being set within the r code itself.

Comment: @user470184 do you want to read a csv file with dates??? I miss something here, you can see my update.

Comment: I'm confused about how to replace the line axis(1, at=1:5, lab=c("01/01/2013" , "01/02/2013" , "01/03/2013" , 
, "01/04/2013" , , "01/05/2013")) with the dates read from the .csv file ? Using your variable can I use something like : axis(1,dat$value) ?